# is there a way to prevent developers from creating any branches in git?

Tags: git-branch

I have code on a master branch, and I never want it to be branched. It holds yang and protobuf code which must always march forward.  If it branched we might release something that cannot upgrade to a later version because the content has diverged.  Is there any way to prevent branching in git?

Answer (score 1):

Make it a *social convention*, not a technical one.

<sup>(likewise, you don't expect your fellow developers to remove all the code from the repository).</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You can engineer a solution like this.  Make one repo that you consider your 'system of record'.  This repo would perhaps only allow you to push to it.  Then a second repo 'free for all' where everyone is allowed to push/branch whatever.  Then you become responsible for pulling from the 'free for all' repo and migrating it over to the 'system of record'.

Answer (score 1):

[Gitolite](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/) has [that functionality](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/aac.html#rwcd).

Answer (score 1):

Preventing git from branching is like preventing vim from adding new lines. Instead of avoiding one of git's most powerful features, I'd recommend adopting a well-defined and controlled release procedure, like [Git Flow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/).